# Java variable substitution when it is reflected, and not

Tags: java, object, variables, substitution, object-oriented-analysis

Like the code shows, as variable x is substituted to list, when the new instance of ListNode is substituted to x.next, it is reflected on both x and list(refer to the comment 1). I think this is because x refers to list.
However, when the new instance is substituted to x, it is reflected on only x, not list(refer to the comment 2).
Could you explain why this happens?

```
    public class Sample {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ListNode list = new ListNode(0, null);
        ListNode x = list;
            //1.ListNode new instance is substituted for both x and list as x refers to list
            x.next = new ListNode(1, null);
            //2.ListNode new instance is substituted only for x, not list
            x = new ListNode(1, null);
    }
}

class ListNode {
    int data;
    ListNode next;

    ListNode(final int data, final ListNode next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `ListNode list` is declared `final`?

Comment: No the final was added automatically by IDE as list can't be changed in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/indrabasak/Books/blob/master/Head%20First%20Java%2C%202nd%20Edition.pdf

Read chapter 3 "Primitives and references" from this book. Your life will become much easier.

Comment: best answer ever

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other languages like C++, most Java variables (except primitives) are references to `Object`s. So, after:

```java
ListNode x = list;
```

both `x` and `list` reference the same object (`x == list`). Any modification you'll do (like changing the `x.next` field) will apply to both variables.

However, you can always change the object `x` is referencing (but not `list`, since it is `final`) and you do it with:

```java
x = new ListNode(1, null);
```

After that `x != list`.

You can test with a primitive type (like `int`) to see what changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I figured out thanks to your explanation!